# Laravel sort table by columns - dynamically reload products

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm currently trying to implement a functionality, to sort a table in Laravel.
What I do, is getting some products from the db, with lots of checks and different search queries, returning them with paginate.
Then, in my view, I have the table for that, with some columns. What I'm trying to achieve is, that clicking on the header of one column, sorts the table by that column.

Here is the code I use to show the table:

Controller:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $productSearch = $request->input('productSearch');
        $splittedProductSearch = explode(' ', $productSearch);
        $searchQuery = "%" . $productSearch . "%";

        $enteredKeywords = $request->input('keywordsArray');
        $keywords1 = [];
        $keywords2 = [];
        $keywords3 = [];
        $keywords4 = [];
        $splittedKeywords = explode(',',$enteredKeywords);
        foreach($splittedKeywords as $key){
            $keywords1[] = ['keywords', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%'];
            $keywords3[] = ['keywords', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%'];
        }

        foreach($splittedProductSearch as $key){
            $keywords1[] = ['name', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%'];
            $keywords2[] = ['name', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%'];
            $keywords3[] = ['name', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%'];
            $keywords4[] = ['name', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%'];
        }

        $selectedSubcategory = $request->subCategorySelect;
        $selectedCategory = "99";

        $categories = Category::all();
        if ($selectedSubcategory) {
            $selectedSubcategoryObject = Subcategory::where('id',$selectedSubcategory)->first();
            $selectedCategory = Category::where('id',$selectedSubcategoryObject->parent_id)->first();
            $keywords1[] = ['category_id','=',$selectedSubcategory];
            $keywords2[] = ['category_id','=',$selectedSubcategory];
            if ($enteredKeywords != "") {
                $products = Product::where($keywords1)->paginate(15);
            } else {
                $products = Product::where($keywords2)->paginate(15);
            }
        } else {
            if ($enteredKeywords != "") {
                $products = Product::where($keywords3)->paginate(15);
            } else {
                $products = Product::where($keywords4)->paginate(15);
            }
        }
        return view('productSearchResult', ['products' => $products, 'categories' => $categories, 'productSearch' => $productSearch,
            'selectedSubCategory' => $selectedSubcategory, 'selectedCategory'=>$selectedCategory, 'enteredKeywords' => $enteredKeywords]);
    }
```

In the view:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Artikelbild
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Artikelnummer
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Name des Artikels
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Beschreibung
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Preis
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Kategorie
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            @foreach($products as $product)
                                <tr class='clickable-row' <?php if($product->stockCount === 0) echo "style='color:red;'";?>data-href="{{url('/product')}}<?php echo '/'.$product->id;?>">
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="/images/{{$product->imageUrl}}" class="productImageSmall"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{$product->id}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{$product->name}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                        if (strlen($product->description) > 30) {
                                            $productShortened = substr($product->description, 0, 30) . "[...]";
                                        } else {
                                            $productShortened = $product->description;
                                        }
                                        echo $productShortened;
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo number_format($product->price, 2, ',', '.');?>€
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{$product->categoryName}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                        {{ $products->links() }}
```

So basically, in the controller I do some search queries, return those in the variable `$products` and then loop over the products with a `foreach`.

What I found out is, that I could change this `$products = Product::where($keywords4)->paginate(15);` to `$products = Product::where($keywords4)->orderBy('price','desc')->paginate(15);` to sort it by descending price, but this would he hardcoded and always sorted by the price. What I thought about is making the header of each column clickable with a link like `?sortBy=price` or something like that, then, in my controller I could check (in every of the four cases where I get my products) to what the GET parameter is set, then I would redirect to the page again. But: This would be a lot of code, as I needed to check for 4 or 5 GET parameters in every of the 4 if clauses, and (what I find worse) is, that the page has to be reloaded completely, always when clicking on the header, which is not nice... I would need to reload it somehow with JS, AJAX, whatever, but how? Is it somehow possible to refresh the `{{$products}}` that I get, so the table gets dynamically reloaded?

What can I do to get this thing working?

Comment: I'd suggest using [dataTables with an AJAX source](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) since it will make things simpler.

Comment: @apokryfos looks interesting, can you provide me an example what I would have to change to get this working? How could I transfer the data I get from the eloquent query to a AJAX table data array, and how can I show the data in the table then?